# Magento - tax calculation for EU customers with 0% VAT issue

Tags: magento, configuration, magento-1.9

I have an issue trying to get the proper price calculation.

I have the following settings:

tax classes for products: taxable goods, shipping

tax classes for customers: AT Private, AT Company, DE Private, DE Company, CH Private, CH Company

tax rates: VAT DE 19%, VAT AT Private 19%, VAT AT Company 0%, VAT CH 0%

tax rule: VAT DE and AT Private for DE Private, DE Company, AT Private - VAT DE

tax rule: AT Company Customers for AT Company - VAT AT Company 0%

tax rule: CH Customers for CH Private and CH Company - VAT CH 0%

In the Configuration:
Sales -> Taxes is set:
Tax calculation - shipping address based

Catalog prices - incl. VAT

Default tax setting for Germany

Cart settings: prices with and without VAT

Origin country: Germany.

The issue is as follows:
Everything is fine when customer is from Germany or it is a private customer from Austria. But when customer from Austria puts his/her VAT ID Number and it is checked as a valid one, Magento doesn't show proper prices. It shows brutto price as it were netto one and gives 0% VAT. It should show netto price and 0% VAT.

Example:
Product brutto price is 100.
Customer from Germany and private from Austria sees in the cart 100 incl. 15,97 (19%) VAT,so netto 84,03.
Customer from Austria with valid VAT ID Number sees in the cart 100 incl. 0 (0%) VAT, so netto 100. This is a mistake. It should be shown 84,03 incl. 0 (0%) VAT.

When I change the catalog prices to be given as netto ones, the cart is shown correctly. But I need brutto catalog prices.

Does someone has a solution for this issue? What rule should I add / change in magento files, that the calculation would be proper?

Many thanks in advance.

Kristoff